# Java Inversion of Control programming assignment

Tags: java, controls, inversion-of-control

I received this programming assignment a while ago, and I'm still confused on the requirements for what looks like inversion of control.

Assignment:
Write a simple random number generator service in Java. The service should provide at least, but not limited to, two different random number generator implementations - one that uses Java's built-in random number generator and another that uses a generator employing an algorithm of the author's choosing. Evaluators should be able to use the code and compiled classes to plug in their own random number generator implementation without recompiling the code.

My question is the last line.  Wouldn't that require some API or interface spec to know how to use another RNG class?  When I did the assignment I had the main program take a classname as the argument, and then call the main method of that class.  Apparently that wasn't the right way to do it since I didn't end up getting the job.

Am I missing something?  Is there a way to do this without making big assumptions about classes that are "plugged in"?

Note:  This was from 2010, it is not a current job interview assignment.  Also, I'm not asking for someone to post the answer to the assignment, just to clarify the last line of the assignment.

TIA

Comment: I had a similar one in 2008, for a scheduler, but that also had kinda AOP-ish elements too, so it was not very difficult to see they wanted Spring...  I think this question wanted to see you can use an IOC container to get the stuff done. However, this question is not fit for [SO], please read the [FAQ]

Answer (score 1):

> Evaluators should be able to use the code and compiled classes to plug
>   in their own random number generator implementation without
>   recompiling the code.

Sounds like they want you to code to an interface. I don't know if they want you to extend the [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class or some other API contract. But they want you to be able to plug-and-play with different randomizers without having to recompile your code.

How this relates to Inversion of Control would be that your class delegates random number generation to the randomizer. This randomizer is passed into the service implementation via a setter or via the constructor.

So your class might look like

```
class RandomizerService{

    private Random rand;

    public RandomizerService{Random rand){
        this.rand = rand;
    }

    public int getRandomInt(){
        return rand.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's more than coding to an interface, which can be hard-coded.  The "without recompiling" means that, as the OP suspects, he needed to do dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

Providing a pluggable architecture for an interface is not that hard. The plain JRE provides the necessary functionality without the need for additional frameworks. So if you have an interface `serviceexample.RandomNumberGenerator` the code for a pluggable RNG could look like this:

```
package serviceexample;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ServiceConfigurationError;
import java.util.ServiceLoader;

public final class RngService
{
  private RngService(){}

  private static final ServiceLoader<RandomNumberGenerator> LOADER
    = ServiceLoader.load(RandomNumberGenerator.class);

  public static RandomNumberGenerator getRandomNumberGenerator()
  {
    return LOADER.iterator().next();
  }

  public static Iterator<RandomNumberGenerator> getAllRandomNumberGenerators()
  {
    return LOADER.iterator();
  }

  public static RandomNumberGenerator getSpecificRandomNumberGenerator(String name)
  {
    try
    {
      return Class.forName(name).asSubclass(RandomNumberGenerator.class).newInstance();
    } catch(InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException | ClassCastException ex)
    {
      throw new ServiceConfigurationError(name, ex);
    }
  }
}
```

This class allows applications to ask for just one implementation, browse through all available implementations or ask for a specific one. The latter could be provided by a system property, e.g. `-Drng=class`. So the simplest use would be `RandomNumberGenerator r=RngService.getRandomNumberGenerator();`. The more advanced use would be:

```
String name=System.getProperty("rng");
RandomNumberGenerator r=name!=null?
  RngService.getSpecificRandomNumberGenerator(name):
  RngService.getRandomNumberGenerator();
```

Existing implementation classes are specified by a file `META-INF/serviceexample.RandomNumberGenerator` in the jar file containing the particular implementation. See also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Service%20Provider